# Two time console show in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, console

**Dobule console show problem in react**
[image: Dobule console show problem in react]

any solution for this problem

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to be able to help. Please show your code (with the `console.log()` call).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that happens because your component is rendered 2 times so, also the `console.log` is executed 2 times, but i'm not sure as you didn't provide any code or information.